# ubuntu 16.4 USB Port

Tags: usb-drive

I installed ubuntu on a windows computer and I keep getting an error on startup that it can't read one of my USB ports. I had the same problem in windows 7 but I went into device manager and disabled it.I have 3 USB ports on my home built computer. How do I disable the USB port 2 in ubuntu?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! If possible, could you edit your post to include the exact text of the error message? Thanks!